# Using a form value in php if/else

Tags: php, sql, forms

The form code :

```
<form method="post">
                <input type="text" name="q" /> 
                <input type="submit" name="search" value="Find Workorder" class="btn btn-success"/>
                </form>
```

example php code :

```
include 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();   
$sql = 'SELECT whatever FROM wherever ORDER BY id DESC';
$rows = $pdo->query($sql);
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) 
{
echo
whatever
}

if ($q)
{
$sql2 = 'SELECT whatever FROM wherever WHERE whatever LIKE '%$q%' ORDER BY id DESC';
$rows = $pdo->query($sql);
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) 
{
echo
whatever
}
```

I keep on getting an undefined variable error, when the variable "q" is obviously being defined whenever a _POST is made, does anyone know why this is?

Comment: `if ($q)`  where is `$q` defined?

Comment: You must have learned php on a stoneage/braindead system where register_globals was still enabled. $q is **VERY** undefined in your code.

Comment: I named the form as "q", whenever you post, does that not convert as $q?

Comment: No, use `if (isset($_POST['q'])) { ... }` instead. That's where q is put.

Comment: ohhh no thats HTML.. `<input type="text" name="q" /> `  how does that define a `php` variable?

Comment: @JoelHinz, good catch what he meant!, post as answer and let him close it

Comment: @spiderman I would have, but it's been closed. :) No biggie, though.